# pyspark.sql Unable to instantiate HiveMetaStoreClient - noclassfound from org.apache.commons.dbcp.connectionfactory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive

With Pyspark (python 3.7.1) am connecting to external hive postgres metastore. Upon running spark.sql("show databases") am getting error `Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient - Caused by: noclassfound from org.apache.commons.dbcp.connectionfactory`

The spark config parameters that connect to external hive postgres metastore are shown in below code snippet. I added the postgres library, set all the connection details in config. Username / password mentioned in config is correct. Still, not clear about the error. The detailed error log is in below code snippet. Anyone has idea how to query with spark.sql ? Thank you,

**pyspark code snippet**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def spark_init():
    spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "10000")
    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "non-strict")
    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","hdfs://xxx:8020/user/hive/warehouse")
    .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://xxx:8020/user/hive/warehouse")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    .config("spark.jars","/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.12.jar")
    .config("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:postgresql://xxx:5432/hive")
    .config("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName","org.postgresql.Driver")
    .config("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","hive")
    .config("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","hive")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
    )

    return spark

spark = spark_init()

spark.sql("show databases").show();
```

**Error log**

```
    Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
20/04/21 12:55:34 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x7fad44a927b8>
20/04/21 12:55:37 WARN metadata.Hive: Failed to register all functions.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3851)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:4105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$client$HiveClientImpl$$client(HiveClientImpl.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:651)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1773)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.datasource.DataSourceProviderFactory.<clinit>(DataSourceProviderFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:7036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.loadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:235)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 85 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ergo.liferunoffinsuranceplatform.com/kdamarla/lip-core-dwh/src/python/venv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ergo.liferunoffinsuranceplatform.com/kdamarla/lip-core-dwh/src/python/venv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o97.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:651)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$client$HiveClientImpl$$client(HiveClientImpl.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3851)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:4105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:237)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1773)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.datasource.DataSourceProviderFactory.<clinit>(DataSourceProviderFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:7036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.loadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:235)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 85 more'
```

Comment: with external hive metastore are you able to connect through hive command prompt ?

Comment: i can connect from hive-shell and do show databases with no issues

Comment: instead of passing     .config("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","hive")
through spark can you use hive-site.xml by setting that in to classpath ?

Comment: yes, i passed them in hive-site.xml as well. maybe will remove them in config ans let you know of the result.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram removed them from script and kept only in hive-site.xml. Still getting unable to instantiate hive metastore. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With Pyspark (python 3.7.1) am connecting to **external** hive postgres metastore.*

---

Either your hive-site.xml is entered wrong entries , or the Metastore service is down.

may be hive site xml is not in the classpath . You can use spark `spark.yarn.dist.files` and specify path to `hive-site.xml` there.

---

Move hive-site.xml from `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml` to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`. Make an entry regarding **hive metastore uris** in this file.

```
# Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.
hive.metastore.uris thrift://<metastore-host>:<metastore-port>
```

sample hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>

      <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>/home/local/hive-metastore-dir/warehouse</value>

      </property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://192.168.122.1:9083</value>
</property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hivedb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>user</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>password</value>
    </property>

    <configuration>
```

Further check this [wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Metastore+Administration)

**UPDATE**

Class not found is pure classpath issue use like this

```
pyspark --jars=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.12.jar
//or
spark-submit --jars=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.12.jar <your py script or app jar>
```

If you want to add all jars with out missing any thing, then use below

```
--jars $(echo //opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')
```

This should have your Commons dbcp jar also in your classpath.

---

*Please dont send all the args from code which is wrong way if jar file will go in to another folder then you need to change the code.*

Comment: Hi @Ram, i have the hive-site.xml with the extermal metastore details specified. i rebooted the machine and my error progressed to unable to instantiate hive metastore with class not found exception from org.apache.commons.dbcp.connectionfactory. i am editing the actual question as well with this log. Thank you

Comment: the metastore-host in thrift uri is the external postgres ip-address or the ip-address where hadoop is installed  ? i didnot have any metastore uri in my hive-site.xml.

Comment: submitted the spark-submit with postgres jar. Still getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory Perhaps, do i need to include any other jar other than postgres ?

Comment: please DONT change question incrementally by updating different things.  my answer will be come stale. since you changed context. ask seperate question for each

Comment: Sure @Ram. i will change. Reg, the latest update to including all jars, can i submit all jars like spark-submit --jars=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark/jars/*.jar script.py ?

Comment: use this `--jars $(echo //opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')  as mentioned
` will create comma seperated list of jars with out missing anything.

Comment: Did like mentioned. spark-submit --jars $(echo //opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') script.py. Still getting unable to instantiate hive metastore  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory. Tried with both pyspark shell and spark-submit. Any hints ?

Comment: within my spark/jars folder, i see that i have 2 postgres.jar files, 1. postgresql-42.2.12.jar  2. postgresql-jdbc.jar. Tried keeoing only latest postgres libraray. still class not found exception. Not exactly sure where i could get this org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory. library. From other SO posts, i see that this error is casued by postgres library.

Comment: the problem is with hive.metastore.uris. i added this and its working fine now. Thank you. Strange that i didnot have this hive.metastore.uris previously and it still worked only with jdbc parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212198/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-user1).